# joomla 2.5 module retrieve data from database

Tags: php, sql, database, joomla, module

i want to retrieve data from database in my module page.for that my helloworld.php put the code

```
// Get a database object
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id, description');
$query->from('#__banners');

// sets up a database query for later execution
$db->setQuery($query);

// fetch result as an object list
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

now i want to show the results in default.php. but when echo $result in default.php it dose not show anything. how to i show the result? how to i get data from #__banners table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$db->loadObjectList()` returns an array which you can't echo. You can create a `foreach` loop like so:

```
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
    echo $row->description;
}
```

Comment: where will be this code? after $result = $db->loadObjectList();    ? or in default.php  ?

Comment: where is your database query? in a helper.php file in or the default.php?

Comment: good good. if this helped solve your problem, please accept the answer

Comment: tnx sir. 1 min pls. by this line $query->select('id, title'); we select some row of table. how to we select all row of a table by one code? if possible

Comment: `$query->select('*');`

Comment: sir one min again. by this line echo $row->description; we show one value of $row. how to show all value of $row?

Comment: please ask a new question. Would be best to avoid additional support in the comments like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245525/how-to-show-all-data-from-joomla-table

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the results from the model method in `view.html.php`.

In `view.html.php`

```
function display($tpl = null) {
  $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('ModelName', 'FrontendModel'); //(or BackendModel)
  $variable = $model->getNameOfModelMethod();

  $this->assignRef('variable', $variable);
 }
```

And in default.php just call `$this->variable`.