# how to show all data from joomla table?

Tags: php, sql, database, joomla, module

recently i learned how to get data from database by this method

```
public static function getdb($params)
{
// Get a database object
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__categories');

// sets up a database query for later execution
$db->setQuery($query);

// fetch result as an object list
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
echo "$row->extension .<br>";
}
}
```

by this line

```
echo "$row->extension .<br>";
```

we get single row value. how to we get all row value of  #__categories? by any short code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `foreach` inside

```
foreach ( $result as $row ) {  // it is like  foreach($objects as $object)
  foreach ($row as $r) {       // it is like  foreach($object as $values)
    echo "$r .<br>";
  }
}
```

But you should print the code in the view not in the model, controller, etc.

Comment: tnx sir. it works. can i use this foreach loop in default.php  ? am a module learner

Comment: Yes you can. But you have to assign it in view.html.php.

Comment: sir this is module not componant. how to show in module tmpl/default.php  ?

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` loop should give you all the rows for your query. Try making a few changes like so:

**helper.php**

```
public static function getdb($params) {

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__categories');

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $result;
}
```

**default.php**

```
$result = modHelloWorldHelper::getdb($params);

foreach ( $result as $row ) {
    echo $row->extension . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: He wants to echo all values from 1 object he gets from the database. This code does the same like his code.

Comment: ah my bad, completely misread it. Thought he wanted all the values from 1 column

Comment: @Lodder it dose not work. and by this code may be i get all value from  extension row. but i want all row value under #__cagegories